# MPFR 3.1.3 fails with "illegal thread local variable reference to regular symbol" on Mac + Intel 15

Tags: macos, intel, ld

I downloaded MPFR 3.1.3 from http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/ and attempted to compile with Intel 15 (`icc --version` returns `icc (ICC) 15.0.3 20150408`) on Mac Yosemite (10.10.4).

The build fails at this point:

```
jrhammon-mac01:build jrhammon$ make
Making all in doc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link icc  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -fp_port -mp -wd1572 -wd265 -wd186 -wd239 -g -O2   -version-info 5:3:1 -Wl,-search_paths_first  -o libmpfr.la -rpath /usr/local/lib exceptions.lo extract.lo uceil_exp2.lo uceil_log2.lo ufloor_log2.lo add.lo add1.lo add_ui.lo agm.lo clear.lo cmp.lo cmp_abs.lo cmp_si.lo cmp_ui.lo comparisons.lo div_2exp.lo div_2si.lo div_2ui.lo div.lo div_ui.lo dump.lo eq.lo exp10.lo exp2.lo exp3.lo exp.lo frac.lo frexp.lo get_d.lo get_exp.lo get_str.lo init.lo inp_str.lo isinteger.lo isinf.lo isnan.lo isnum.lo const_log2.lo log.lo modf.lo mul_2exp.lo mul_2si.lo mul_2ui.lo mul.lo mul_ui.lo neg.lo next.lo out_str.lo printf.lo vasprintf.lo const_pi.lo pow.lo pow_si.lo pow_ui.lo print_raw.lo print_rnd_mode.lo reldiff.lo round_prec.lo set.lo setmax.lo setmin.lo set_d.lo set_dfl_prec.lo set_exp.lo set_rnd.lo set_f.lo set_prc_raw.lo set_prec.lo set_q.lo set_si.lo set_str.lo set_str_raw.lo set_ui.lo set_z.lo sqrt.lo sqrt_ui.lo sub.lo sub1.lo sub_ui.lo rint.lo ui_div.lo ui_sub.lo urandom.lo urandomb.lo get_z_exp.lo swap.lo factorial.lo cosh.lo sinh.lo tanh.lo sinh_cosh.lo acosh.lo asinh.lo atanh.lo atan.lo cmp2.lo exp_2.lo asin.lo const_euler.lo cos.lo sin.lo tan.lo fma.lo fms.lo hypot.lo log1p.lo expm1.lo log2.lo log10.lo ui_pow.lo ui_pow_ui.lo minmax.lo dim.lo signbit.lo copysign.lo setsign.lo gmp_op.lo init2.lo acos.lo sin_cos.lo set_nan.lo set_inf.lo set_zero.lo powerof2.lo gamma.lo set_ld.lo get_ld.lo cbrt.lo volatile.lo fits_sshort.lo fits_sint.lo fits_slong.lo fits_ushort.lo fits_uint.lo fits_ulong.lo fits_uintmax.lo fits_intmax.lo get_si.lo get_ui.lo zeta.lo cmp_d.lo erf.lo inits.lo inits2.lo clears.lo sgn.lo check.lo sub1sp.lo version.lo mpn_exp.lo mpfr-gmp.lo mp_clz_tab.lo sum.lo add1sp.lo free_cache.lo si_op.lo cmp_ld.lo set_ui_2exp.lo set_si_2exp.lo set_uj.lo set_sj.lo get_sj.lo get_uj.lo get_z.lo iszero.lo cache.lo sqr.lo int_ceil_log2.lo isqrt.lo strtofr.lo pow_z.lo logging.lo mulders.lo get_f.lo round_p.lo erfc.lo atan2.lo subnormal.lo const_catalan.lo root.lo sec.lo csc.lo cot.lo eint.lo sech.lo csch.lo coth.lo round_near_x.lo constant.lo abort_prec_max.lo stack_interface.lo lngamma.lo zeta_ui.lo set_d64.lo get_d64.lo jn.lo yn.lo rem1.lo get_patches.lo add_d.lo sub_d.lo d_sub.lo mul_d.lo div_d.lo d_div.lo li2.lo rec_sqrt.lo min_prec.lo buildopt.lo digamma.lo bernoulli.lo isregular.lo set_flt.lo get_flt.lo scale2.lo set_z_exp.lo ai.lo gammaonethird.lo grandom.lo  -lgmp 
libtool: link: icc -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libmpfr.4.dylib  .libs/exceptions.o .libs/extract.o .libs/uceil_exp2.o .libs/uceil_log2.o .libs/ufloor_log2.o .libs/add.o .libs/add1.o .libs/add_ui.o .libs/agm.o .libs/clear.o .libs/cmp.o .libs/cmp_abs.o .libs/cmp_si.o .libs/cmp_ui.o .libs/comparisons.o .libs/div_2exp.o .libs/div_2si.o .libs/div_2ui.o .libs/div.o .libs/div_ui.o .libs/dump.o .libs/eq.o .libs/exp10.o .libs/exp2.o .libs/exp3.o .libs/exp.o .libs/frac.o .libs/frexp.o .libs/get_d.o .libs/get_exp.o .libs/get_str.o .libs/init.o .libs/inp_str.o .libs/isinteger.o .libs/isinf.o .libs/isnan.o .libs/isnum.o .libs/const_log2.o .libs/log.o .libs/modf.o .libs/mul_2exp.o .libs/mul_2si.o .libs/mul_2ui.o .libs/mul.o .libs/mul_ui.o .libs/neg.o .libs/next.o .libs/out_str.o .libs/printf.o .libs/vasprintf.o .libs/const_pi.o .libs/pow.o .libs/pow_si.o .libs/pow_ui.o .libs/print_raw.o .libs/print_rnd_mode.o .libs/reldiff.o .libs/round_prec.o .libs/set.o .libs/setmax.o .libs/setmin.o .libs/set_d.o .libs/set_dfl_prec.o .libs/set_exp.o .libs/set_rnd.o .libs/set_f.o .libs/set_prc_raw.o .libs/set_prec.o .libs/set_q.o .libs/set_si.o .libs/set_str.o .libs/set_str_raw.o .libs/set_ui.o .libs/set_z.o .libs/sqrt.o .libs/sqrt_ui.o .libs/sub.o .libs/sub1.o .libs/sub_ui.o .libs/rint.o .libs/ui_div.o .libs/ui_sub.o .libs/urandom.o .libs/urandomb.o .libs/get_z_exp.o .libs/swap.o .libs/factorial.o .libs/cosh.o .libs/sinh.o .libs/tanh.o .libs/sinh_cosh.o .libs/acosh.o .libs/asinh.o .libs/atanh.o .libs/atan.o .libs/cmp2.o .libs/exp_2.o .libs/asin.o .libs/const_euler.o .libs/cos.o .libs/sin.o .libs/tan.o .libs/fma.o .libs/fms.o .libs/hypot.o .libs/log1p.o .libs/expm1.o .libs/log2.o .libs/log10.o .libs/ui_pow.o .libs/ui_pow_ui.o .libs/minmax.o .libs/dim.o .libs/signbit.o .libs/copysign.o .libs/setsign.o .libs/gmp_op.o .libs/init2.o .libs/acos.o .libs/sin_cos.o .libs/set_nan.o .libs/set_inf.o .libs/set_zero.o .libs/powerof2.o .libs/gamma.o .libs/set_ld.o .libs/get_ld.o .libs/cbrt.o .libs/volatile.o .libs/fits_sshort.o .libs/fits_sint.o .libs/fits_slong.o .libs/fits_ushort.o .libs/fits_uint.o .libs/fits_ulong.o .libs/fits_uintmax.o .libs/fits_intmax.o .libs/get_si.o .libs/get_ui.o .libs/zeta.o .libs/cmp_d.o .libs/erf.o .libs/inits.o .libs/inits2.o .libs/clears.o .libs/sgn.o .libs/check.o .libs/sub1sp.o .libs/version.o .libs/mpn_exp.o .libs/mpfr-gmp.o .libs/mp_clz_tab.o .libs/sum.o .libs/add1sp.o .libs/free_cache.o .libs/si_op.o .libs/cmp_ld.o .libs/set_ui_2exp.o .libs/set_si_2exp.o .libs/set_uj.o .libs/set_sj.o .libs/get_sj.o .libs/get_uj.o .libs/get_z.o .libs/iszero.o .libs/cache.o .libs/sqr.o .libs/int_ceil_log2.o .libs/isqrt.o .libs/strtofr.o .libs/pow_z.o .libs/logging.o .libs/mulders.o .libs/get_f.o .libs/round_p.o .libs/erfc.o .libs/atan2.o .libs/subnormal.o .libs/const_catalan.o .libs/root.o .libs/sec.o .libs/csc.o .libs/cot.o .libs/eint.o .libs/sech.o .libs/csch.o .libs/coth.o .libs/round_near_x.o .libs/constant.o .libs/abort_prec_max.o .libs/stack_interface.o .libs/lngamma.o .libs/zeta_ui.o .libs/set_d64.o .libs/get_d64.o .libs/jn.o .libs/yn.o .libs/rem1.o .libs/get_patches.o .libs/add_d.o .libs/sub_d.o .libs/d_sub.o .libs/mul_d.o .libs/div_d.o .libs/d_div.o .libs/li2.o .libs/rec_sqrt.o .libs/min_prec.o .libs/buildopt.o .libs/digamma.o .libs/bernoulli.o .libs/isregular.o .libs/set_flt.o .libs/get_flt.o .libs/scale2.o .libs/set_z_exp.o .libs/ai.o .libs/gammaonethird.o .libs/grandom.o   -lgmp  -mp -g -O2 -Wl,-search_paths_first   -mp -install_name  /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib -compatibility_version 6 -current_version 6.3 -Wl,-single_module
icc: command line remark #10148: option '-mp' not supported
icc: command line remark #10148: option '-mp' not supported
ld: illegal thread local variable reference to regular symbol __tls___mpfr_allocate_func for architecture x86_64
make[2]: *** [libmpfr.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have never seen this error before.  Is it a bug in MPFR, the Intel compiler or the Mac toolchain?  I am using the system install of GMP (from Homebrew), which I assume is built with Clang, not Intel.  Is there a C ABI incompatibility issue here with TLS?

I found https://github.com/feeley/gambit/issues/109 and https://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/ticket/1547, which suggest that it is a Mac issue, but I am able to build with `CC=clang` so I guess it has something to do with Intel.

Answer (score 1):

I have got MPFR to build in the past with Intel compilers, but (apparently) had to apply this patch: https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild-easyconfigs/blob/master/easybuild/easyconfigs/m/MPFR/MPFR_ictce_remove-deprecated-mp.patch  .

Maybe the warnings you're getting aren't so harmless as they seem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not resolve the problem.  I will keep looking for solutions.